# Media library filtered results are broken after a new media item is added

Tags: views, media, 10

After recently updating from Drupal 9.5.11 to 10.1.5 we have spotted some issues with the results displayed in the media library widget.

Basically if I filter results, for example on the string "horris" then insert a new image with the string "horris" in the name, when I the filter on "horris" after the addition, the results are incorrectly returned, visually they look ok, but the numbering applied to the results is broken so for example I might on inspection of the HTML see 2 x 0 ID result entries (both results in the screen grabs have the same ID and value). This means that I can then select an image and get a different one inserted into the node field (in my screen grab scenario, selecting the "horris" image results in "horris 1" getting added to my underlying node's field.)

Clearing redis cache resolves the issue, until it happens again.
I have for the time being disabled caching on the media library views which works-around the issue but i'd like to understand why this occurring now and wasn't an issue in Drupal 9.
Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems more of a bug report than a question of the sort that can get an answer here. In the first place I would try to reproduce the bug on a basic Drupal installation.

Comment: I've had something very similar on my project. I'm 99% sure the Media Library Widget is bugged when combined with Views exposed filters. I'm trying to create a reproducable bug report (I'm not using Redis on my site). I'm curently using the same workaround with disabled views caching.

Comment: @Hudri please post the bug report if you manage to reproduce

Comment: This is a reproducable bug, opened [issue 3401815 on d.o](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3401815)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug which should be reported on the appropriate issue queue on drupal.org.